# How to move the animated contents back to normal position off hover, using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hover

I have a horizontal menu and I want to give the effect move 20px left "on hover" and move back to the same  position "off hover". I want to know how to move it back "off hover" using JQuery. Could you guys help me out regarding this? here is my code.

**JQuery:**

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $("div.menu li").OnMousehover(function () {
         $("li").animate({ left: '20px' });
     });
 });
```

**ASP.NET:**

```
<div>
<asp:Menu ID="Menu" runat="server" CssClass="menu" EnableViewState="false" IncludeStyleBlock="false" Orientation="Horizontal">
  <Items>
    <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Page1.aspx" Text="Page1" />
    <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Page2.aspx" Text="Page2" />
    <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Page3.aspx" Text="Page3" />
    <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Page4.aspx" Text="Page4" />
    <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Page5.aspx" Text="Page5" />
  </Items>
</asp:Menu>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`.hover()`](https://api.jquery.com/hover/) will get the job done.

```
$(document).ready(function (){
     $("ul.menu li").hover(
         function() {
             $(this).animate({ left: '-20px' });
         },
         function() {
             $(this).animate({ left: '0' });
         }
     );
});
```

<kbd>[Demo](http://jsbin.com/kevevovafi/edit?html,js,output)</kbd>